# How to use class instead of ID for jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've read through the similar questions but I can't find an answer. I have the following jquery code for a `sliding panel`. I want to use `classes` instead of an `id`, but nothing seems to work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
<style> 
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
</style>


<body>
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I believe the short way to answer is `$(".className");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add class `attribute` in `html` element as like `class="flip"`

Now you can use `class` in **jquery** using dot (`.`) so you have to use as `$(".flip")`

Also you can give `css` with `class` in same way

See below answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style> 
.flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

.panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
</style>


<body>
<div id="flip" class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel" class="panel">Hello world!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I think I wasn't clear: I want the style associated with the IDs as well, is that possible? Because I can't reuse the IDs. My goal is to have the script function and associated style applied to multiple DIVs.

Comment: Weird it wasn't working for me earlier. I think I must have accidentally skipped a step. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Use `next` with class to `slideToggle` your div like below.

```js
$(".flip").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

.panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
  <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
  <div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
  <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
</body>
```

Using `next` with `this` works with multi pal div. Catching class for toggle break your code for multi pal div.

Comment: Thanks I'll research this more, I'm new to coding. Much appreciated!